# Value of 'this' for VueJs 2 in promise

Tags: vuejs2

Learning Vue for a simple admin panel project.  I cannot access my Vue instance local variables in a method's returned promise using 'this'.

I am only able to access it by directly calling the vue instance itself.  is this the correct way to handle this.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()
const currentUser = auth.currentUser

// firebase collections
const categoryCollection = db.collection('predefinedCategories')

var example2 = new Vue({ 
  el: '#components-demo',
  data: {
      message: 'Message',
  },
  methods: {
    initMessage: function () {
      categoryCollection.get().then(
        function(querySnapshot) {
        message = querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data(), doc.data().name);
          console.log(example2.$data.message);
          console.log(this.data.message);
        });
      });
    },
    checkMessage: function () {
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  }
})
```

console.log(this.data.message) should give me 'Message'.  Instead it gives me undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in the `.then()` callback no longer refers to your Vue instance, because it is scoped in a function. You can of course proxy it to another variable, but since you are using ES6 already, you can use arrow function. The major advantage of arrow function is that it preserves the lexical `this`.

Also, if you want to refer to the app's `message` data, it should be referenced as `this.message` and not `this.data.message`.

```
initMessage: function () {
  categoryCollection.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    message = querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(this.message);
    });
  });
},
```

Comment: This worked terry.  And yours did too James.  Thanks.  Looks like i got some reading up to do on ES6.